# Объясните пожалуйста приоритет перезагрузки типа по умолчанию шаблона и специализации этого типа

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T = int>
class MyClass {
public:
    void f() { cout << "D"; }
};

template<>
class MyClass<int> {
public:
    void f() { cout << "S1"; }
};

template<>
class MyClass<double> {
public:
    void f() { cout << "S2"; }
};


int main() {
    MyClass<double> a; // 1
    a.f();

    MyClass<> b; // 2
    b.f();

    MyClass<int> c; // 3
    c.f();

    return 0;
}
```

Почему `template<class T = int>` более приоритетно чем

```
template<>
class MyClass<int>
```

для 3 ?

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста приоритет перезагрузки типа по умолчанию шаблона и специализации этого типа. Что более приоритетно для строки 3

Comment: Ничего не понял. Для 3 будет использоваться вариант `template<>
class MyClass<int>`. С чего вы взяли, что будет использоваться `template<class T = int> class MyClass`?

Comment: А пусть автор вопроса скажет какой компилятор он использует, может там что-то экзотичное и поэтому там другой результат?

Comment: Т.е. вы утверждаете что данная ситуация - Unspecified behaviour или implemented-defined ? (прошу не путать с Undefined behabiour)

Answer (score 2):

Приоритет имеет, естественно, явная специализация. Так что в обоих случаях

```
MyClass<> b; // 2
b.f();                 //S1

MyClass<int> c; // 3
c.f();                 //S1
```

используется специализация

```
template<>
class MyClass<int> {
public:
    void f() { cout << "S1\n"; }
};
```

См. тут - http://ideone.com/jj6xtH

Comment: А template<> class MyClass<double> { public:     void f() { cout << "S2"; }  } не явная ? Есле следовать вашей логики то 2 явные специализации и потому ошибка компиляции изза многозначности, но её нет.

Comment: Для `c` указано явно `int`, для `b` тип `int` указан как тип по умолчанию. Значит, обе используют `MyClass<int>`. Такая специализация есть - используем ее, а не сам обобщенный шаблон. Наличие специализации для `double` играет роль только для `a`, где указан этот тип.

Comment: Можно proof предоставить. На каких правилах основан переход от версии шаблона с типом по умолчанию к версии шаблона со специализацией этого типа. Мне важно понять что это всё таки implemented-defined ситуация или в соответствии со стандартам.

Comment: Давайте так - вы согласны, что при наличии `template<class T> MyClass` и `template<> MyClass<int>` для `MyClass<int>` будет выбрана специализация? Да или нет? Если нет - разговор окончен. Если да - то **запись `MyClass<>` при наличии `template<class T = int> MyClass` просто эквивалентна записи `MyClass<int>` и не более того**. И разговор опять окончен...

Comment: Ненаучный стиль дискуссии какойто. Мы ж не в церкви. я просил ссылку на главу стандарта.

Comment: Я с вами, кстати говоря, не дискутирую. Я просто объясняю :) Если вы считаете это дискуссией - нет вопросов, берите стандарт и доказывайте, что это не так :) Мы не в церкви, и милостыню я подавать не намерен. Все, дальше - самостоятельно, моя работа на этом закончена, я и так затратил на объяснение очевидного слишком много времени.

Comment: Спасибо, но я лишь обозначил что не могу расценивать объяснение как исчерпывающие без ссылки на стандарт так мне важны нюансы. Но я не принкждаю вас прикладывать дополнительные усилия и лезьть в стпндарт, если лениво. Это скорее для других.

Comment: Кстати далеко не факт что в стандарте вообще об этом что либо сказано это вполне может быть случай implemented-defined поведения.